# scanf_s doesn't work visual studio

Tags: scanf

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

vis studio 2017,
doesn't matter what i do,

```
int main(){
    char c = 's';
    scanf_s(" %c", &c, 1);
}
```

simple program, changing scanf_s line to

```
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

again to,

```
scanf_s("%1c", &c, 1);
```

etc nothing works I get a debug error

```
scanf_s(" %1c", &c, sizeof(c));
```

again, error, I don't know what the problem is

```
scanf_s("%c",&c);
```

it brings me to this line in debugger:

```
{
    return __stdio_common_vfscanf(
        _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_SCANF_OPTIONS | _CRT_INTERNAL_SCANF_SECURECRT,
        _Stream, _Format, _Locale, _ArgList);
}
#endif
```

Comment: it is during runtime, not compile error

Comment: yep tried that, literally nothing is working, keeps bringing me to the same spot in debugger, ill try making a new project...

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and it fixed the problem